# Getting Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 65 Error with Xcode 5.1 .

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7.1, xcode5.1

Sadly, I updated my iOS from **7.0.4** to **7.1** and hence was forced to upgrade Xcode from **5.0** to **5.1**, after which I had to solve several issues.

But I am not able to resolve the following error.

It would be great if you can help resolving it.

I am using **iOSSdk6.1** as target SDK with **Xcode 5.1**

Here are the logs below:

```
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 65



########### TESTS #############
Use the following variables when debugging this script; note that they may change on recursions
BUILD_DIR = /Users/rahulg/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TheEngineSample-abaidaurzaogqcbzpmqjesdtvulv/Build/Products
BUILD_ROOT = /Users/rahulg/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TheEngineSample-abaidaurzaogqcbzpmqjesdtvulv/Build/Products
CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR = /Users/rahulg/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TheEngineSample-abaidaurzaogqcbzpmqjesdtvulv/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos
BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR = /Users/rahulg/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TheEngineSample-abaidaurzaogqcbzpmqjesdtvulv/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos
CONFIGURATION_TEMP_DIR = /Users/rahulg/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TheEngineSample-abaidaurzaogqcbzpmqjesdtvulv/Build/Intermediates/TheAmazingAudioEngine.build/Debug-iphoneos
TARGET_BUILD_DIR = /Users/rahulg/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TheEngineSample-abaidaurzaogqcbzpmqjesdtvulv/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos
XCode has selected SDK: iphoneos with version: 6.1 (although back-targetting: 4.3)
...therefore, OTHER_SDK_TO_BUILD = iphonesimulator6.1
xcodebuild -project "/Users/rahulg/Desktop/TheAmazingAudioEngine-master/TheAmazingAudioEngine.xcodeproj" -configuration "Debug" -target "TheAmazingAudioEngine" -sdk "iphonesimulator6.1" build RUN_CLANG_STATIC_ANALYZER=NO BUILD_DIR="/Users/rahulg/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TheEngineSample-abaidaurzaogqcbzpmqjesdtvulv/Build/Products" BUILD_ROOT="/Users/rahulg/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TheEngineSample-abaidaurzaogqcbzpmqjesdtvulv/Build/Products" CALLED_FROM_MASTER=1
Build settings from command line:
    BUILD_DIR = /Users/rahulg/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TheEngineSample-abaidaurzaogqcbzpmqjesdtvulv/Build/Products
    BUILD_ROOT = /Users/rahulg/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TheEngineSample-abaidaurzaogqcbzpmqjesdtvulv/Build/Products
    CALLED_FROM_MASTER = 1
    RUN_CLANG_STATIC_ANALYZER = NO
    SDKROOT = iphonesimulator6.1

=== BUILD TARGET TheAmazingAudioEngine OF PROJECT TheAmazingAudioEngine WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===

Check dependencies
No architectures to compile for (ARCHS=i386 x86_64, VALID_ARCHS=armv7).

** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    Check dependencies
(1 failure)
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 65
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue and I resolved it by editing the scheme of my target into release mode. (Build configuration = release)

I hope that helps you to resolve your problem.